# Create tablespace in postgresql using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I want to create a tablespace in postgresql on the fly using Spring Data JPA.
To do that, I used Native query from EntityManager:

```
@Service
public class DatabaseService {
    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void createTableSpace(String name, String path) {

        String query = "CREATE TABLESPACE "
        + name + " "
        + "OWNER  postgres"
        + " LOCATION" + " '" + path + "'";

        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
        q.executeUpdate();


    }

}
```

After Execute of the code above, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: CREATE TABLESPACE cannot run inside a transaction block
```

So, I removed the @Transactional from createTableSpace function;
After re-executing the code I get another error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

So, how can I handle this situation?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? This is typically a job of the DBA and requires that your application runs with superuser privileges which in itself is a really bad idea.

Comment: The requirement of my application needs that, i want to create new directory each year, so, the client can separate business data per year

Comment: You don't need tablespaces for that, you need a schema

Comment: did you mean that i have to create a new database each year in the same default tablespace ??

Comment: If you want a new "namespace" each year, create a new schema in the database you are using. A database and a schema are two very different things. What are you planing to do with that tablespace anyway? Do you re-create all your tables in that tablespace?

Comment: yes i have, that column , but after 3 or 4 *years, we need to query a lot of record , instead of per year is little bit limited

Comment: You should look into [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) then. Just creating a tablespace won't magically move "some" rows to a different tablespace. All rows of a single table are always stored in the same tablespace.

Comment: can you give any suggestion on how to edit my database design with Fiscal year handling strategies in concederation.